# Characteristics of abelian groups

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A,\ B,\ C$ are each abelian and of infinite cardinality, then is it inherently true that:
$$
(B-C)\times A = (A\times B)-(B\times C)
$$
When I visualize/graph this idea using these sets as an example:
$$
(\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Z})\times \mathbb{N} = (\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{N})-(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{N})
$$
I get the same looking graph, but maths can be tricky sometimes and two graphs may not always mean the same thing. Does this work for ALL abelian groups of infinite cardinality?

Comment: What is $B-C{}$?

Comment: It is the difference between the sets $B$ and $C$. That is, The points only $B$ has and $C$ does not.

Comment: Then I think the words "abelian group" and "characteristics" are totally irrelevant, and as it is written, the question makes little sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is true for any sets, and, as Alejo points in a comment, it has nothing to do with group structure (I think you should take out the tag about groups).
\begin{align}
(B - C) \times A
&= \{ (x,y) : x \in B - C,\, y \in A\}\\
&= \{ (x,y) : x \in B,\, x \notin C,\, y \in A \}\\
&= \{ (x,y) : x \in B, \, y \in A \} - \{ (x,y) : x \in C,\, y \in A\}\\
&= B \times A - C \times A.
\end{align}